# What is the difference between the terms wave, waveform, and signal?

Tags: signal, signal-processing

What is the difference between wave, waveform, and signal? Or do they have the same meaning? Can they be used in place of one another?

Comment: Read this: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-wave-and-signal

Comment: @Whiskeyjack yeah, but the OP should read it with a grain of salt. "A wave needs a medium" and "for example, light waves" in the same answer...

Answer (score 4):

A **signal** is simply something observable changing across one or multiple dimensions. As that, it carries some changing state, which means it has some information¹.

For example, air pressure changing over time might be an audio signal, brightness changing over length might be a barcode (signal), and voltage changing over time is what we typically call an electric signal.

Now, a **wave** is usually a *physical entity* that actually fulfills a periodic, harmonic motion. As that, it is a special kind of signal.

**Waveform** is a term from the radio (and possibly audio) engineering. In that, you modify a (usually harmonic), periodic signal (i.e. a *wave*) with varying parameters (i.e. another signal) to give it the *form* you want. Radio modulations are a typical example of that – *FM broadcasting* is a classical waveform to modify radio waves according to another signal (in that case, audio that you want to broadcast).

I'd strongly recommend using *waveform* only in a context where the usage of "I know there's information in this wave's modification over time" is important, *wave* only when you have a (typically propagating) periodic signal, and *signal* whenever you describe something changing in general.

People that do a lot of signal processing might actually imply periodic nature if they read *wave*. Things like "square wave" already feel a bit off, because they're not harmonic (within finite bandwidth).

---

¹I'll not go into the information theory aspects of that, because it will quickly expand far beyond the scope of this question, and will lead to me explaining a lot of stochastics.

Answer (score 0):

By definition a signal is something that carries information. A waveform is a representation of physical quantity such as voltage or a current over time. If this physical quantity carries information then it is a signal.

In practice, however, the terms signal and waveform are often used synonymously.

Comment: are wave and waveform same terms?

Comment: Sorry. No they are not the same. A wave is a propagating physical property.

Comment: I guess the problem arises from the fact that in electronics people use (rather loosely) the term "wave" as a shorthand for "waveform". Neither of those, by the way, need to be periodic, nor harmonic (oscilloscope triggering in the pre-digital era is probably the cause for this misunderstanding) .